# Which one is faster? A NAS device or a web server on RasPi B+

Tags: networking, web-server, filesystem

I'm currently making a project with Raspberry Pi B+. I want to create a solution through which we can access files from a external HDD from anywhere (over the Internet).

After googling, I found 2 ways: either create a NAS or a web server (like cloud) on Raspberry Pi.

As this project is going to be evaluated at the end and for them to accept it, it should have best performance 'possible'. I would really love NAS on the Raspberry Pi but if a normal cloud like server is faster, I would go for it.

Besides, I'm using 2 Raspberry Pi B+ boards. Can clustering give decent performance? Can it be functional for home purposes for 1 or 2 people max to watch movies or view documents?

Comment: i have both. debian based NAS (non Raspi) where I currently store back ups and media content for my local network and a "Seafile" cloud on raspi with data i want to access from all over the world. for the seafile cloud the raspi is fast enought. the limit in speed is here my internet connection.
The NAS is a old AMD with 100W TPD so it's not running 24/7; only when someone is at home. The Raspi consumes with two 128GB sticks less then 10W and runs 24/7 other devices Mac, NAS, WinPC sync with Seafile when switched on.

Comment: *"Can clustering give decent performance?"* -> Depends how strictly you want to define "clustering".  If you mean two pis, one behind the other, one doing load balancing, etc., sure -- but it is hard to see how that would be necessary in the context you describe.   Beyond that you've asked a pretty vague, opinion based question since you don't mention any specific software.  "Which is faster, cloud service or NAS?" is unanswerable in that form.  Remember, **this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.**  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) with the [`mod_dirlisting`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModDirlisting) module. You can see an example [here](http://dev.hackers.fi/). It is lightweight, fast, secure, simple, configurable, and reliable.

With this configuration, I usually share files, and I can even stream videos over the Internet.

Please note that `mod_dirlisting` is only intended to serve files over HTTP (i.e. read only). If you want to create, update, or delete files, you will need the [`mod_webdav`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModWebDAV) module.